find shift in time series
I have two time series of different length, named speed_A and speed_B. Signal speed_B is quit short and has a time shift compared to speed_A.
What is the best way to compute the time shift between both signals?
I tried scipy.signal.correlate but that nan for the correlation.
Thanks

What's the expected output for this example? Can you add minimal code with a sample?

I created two TS , 1 a subset of the other, correlation 'worked' for my (trivial) example, sharing your code would be helpful.
